# Queue Element use in Gstreamer Pipelines

Tags: queue, gstreamer

gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc  
! queue ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay 
! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=VP8,payload=96 
! webrtcbin name=sendrecv

In this pipeline I don't understand the need for queue element after videotestsrc ?

Can someone throw some light on the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly for the buffering purpose. queue can hold the frames until vp8enc is done encoding current frame and ready to consume next one.

You read more about buffering in gstreamer here https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/buffering.html?gi-language=c

Comment: Thanks Akshay. Is the buffering needed  even when vp8 enc is configured so that no B-frames are encoded ?

Comment: I am afraid I don't have answer to that as I haven't tried it but it still seems logical to have queue as the pipeline has to store next frames somewhere while the I and P frames are being encoded.